# When is sizeof(myPOD) too big for pass by value on x64?

Tags: c++, c, x86, 64-bit, x86-64

I expect no difference when it comes to structures that are up to 8 bytes in size, but what about bigger POD types? Does pass by value become more expensive the moment the type's size exceeds machine word size or is there something else (like cache line size) that can affect the performance?

I'm mainly interested in x64, but feel free to include some numbers for x86 as well.

Clarifications:

- I'm probably thinking too narrowly because I'm not aware of everything that plays a role in this (registers, calling conventions, compiler optimizations). I'm mainly interested in Microsoft's C++ compiler and it only uses __fastcall.
- I'm interested if there is any kind of general recommendation when it comes to parameter passing knowing the architecture, type size, cache size, etc. Something like: "Prefer passing the type by value when it's smaller than N bytes." where N is something that can be derived from the things we know.

Comment: At some point, well past 8 bytes, the compiler generates code to create a local copy and passes a pointer to that copy.  Just try it out, look at the generated machine code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're confusing two separate issues. You can pass *any* object by value (as long as it is copyable).

Whether or not it will be passed *in a register* or on the stack depends on the implementation and specifically, the calling convention used.

Under some calling conventions, parameters larger than 8 bytes (the general-purpose register size) will be passed on the stack. Under other calling conventions, they may simply be split across several registers.

Under some, it is possible that objects are *never* passed in registers, regardless of their size.

Similarly, SIMD values (SSE/AVX) may be passed in registers in some calling conventions, but will always be put on the stack in others. And the same may be true for scalar floating-point values.

But what you're asking can't really be meaningfully answered. The speed of copying an object is affected by the object's size, yes. If the object is a POD type, and it fits in a register, then it *can* be copied with a simple `mov` instruction. Whether or not the compiler will *do* that is up to the compiler.

And obviously, the large the object is, the more cache space it takes up, which means you'll get more cache misses.

But this is all so vague that it is next to useless. We don't know what your object looks like, and we don't know what your code *does* with it. If you have a *specific* type in mind, then write a benchmark to see how it is handled by the compiler.

**In response to your edit**

> I'm interested if there is any kind of general recommendation when it comes to parameter passing knowing the architecture, type size, cache size, etc. Something like: "Prefer passing the type by value when it's smaller than N bytes.

First, trust your compiler. It will aggressively optimize copies away in many situations, so even if you *do* pass a large object by value, it's unlikely to be a measurable problem.

Second, you're looking at a microoptimization which is unlikely to make a noticeable difference either way. For small objects, passing by value avoids a pointer indirection, so it's probably slightly faster. At some point, this becomes overwhelmed by the cost of copying (assuming the object *is* copied, see above). For *very* large objects (for the sake of argument, let's say 500 bytes or above, so large that objects *normally* don't reach it), you should definitely pass by reference.

But for objects of 8, 16, 24, 40 bytes? Who knows? Who cares? It's unlikely to make a measurable difference in real code.

Which leads me to the two rules of thumb:

1. do what seems natural: if passing by copy makes your code simpler or cleaner, do that.
2. if performance matters, then (1) make sure that what you're looking at actually has *any* noticeable impact on your performance at all. Measure it. If it affects performance, then it can be measured. If it can't be measured, then the difference in performance, by definition, cannot be noticeable.

So, in short:

- for primitive types, pass by value.
- for very large types, pass by reference.
- for everything else, stop worrying and spend your time on something productive.

Comment: I'm aware that any object can be passed by value, I just wanted some hard numbers provided that I know all the details. It just seems that I don't know everything that comes into play. See my clarifications.

Comment: If you want hard numbers, measure it. :) Incidentally, that is also the only rule worth following if you're concerned about performance: if you need to know which is faster, measure it. If you can't measure the difference, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I guess what I was looking for was documentation for x64 calling convention. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286(v=vs.100).aspx explains this nicely: "Any argument that doesn’t fit in 8 bytes, or is not 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, must be passed by reference. There is no attempt to spread a single argument across multiple registers."

Answer (score 0):

You should be concerned of two things - data copying and stack usage.

Data copying takes time. The larger the structure, the longer it will takes to copy it. Whether it's a performance or not depends on how often you do it, and what are the performance requirements of your code.

The stack is large, but isn't infinite. Passing large structures by value, especially if combined with recursion, can easily cause it to overflow.

With x86_64 (using the WIN64 or Linux conventions), there's the smaller point of passing data in registers. If parameters are up to 8 bytes each, the first 6 are passed in registers, which is faster. With x86, most conventions doesn't do it (the Linux kernel, however uses 3 registers for parameters).
Using reigsters is somewhat faster. But the difference between passing 8 bytes using stack or a register is small, compared to the difference between copying 8 bytes and 1000 bytes.

Comment: "x86 doesn't do it by default"? What? x86 doesn't do anything by default, so there is nothing to "override". It's up to the compiler(s) to decide on a calling convention.

Comment: @jalf, yes, I wasn't accurate. Normal x86 calling conventions, i.e. Linux and Windows, don't do it.