# Should I regularely pass the std::string by reference to optimize time of execution C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14

How to pass the std::string to the function to gain in speed of execution for this code snippet (strictly C++14, function only prints or logs received string):

```
#include <iostream>

void myFunction1(std::string msg)// this is faster ?
{
    std::cout << msg;
}

void myFunction2(const std::string& msg)// to this one is fastest?
{
    std::cout << msg;
}

int main()
{
    myFunction("Hello World");
    myFunction("Long string of 127 characters");
    myFunction("Another long string of 256 characters");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394674/when-is-sizeofmypod-too-big-for-pass-by-value-on-x64

Comment: Please don't remove the `c++` tag. If you want answers to be limited to a certain version, add `c++??` in addition to `c++`, and additionally mention it in the question body.

Comment: Passing by reference instead of by value is **always** faster than passing by value for any type larger than a pointer.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, strictly speaking that is not always true.

Comment: In your example you don't provide `std::string` as an argument, but a string literal that is converted to a temporary `std::string`. If that is the main usage of your function, the answer to your question is not trivial and may become surprising. And I vote for reopening the question.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov  OK strictly speaking it's never slower.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, even that is not true at least if you count not only passing but also usage. For example, it is better to pass `std::string_view` by value rather than by const reference, even though it is of size of 2 pointers. Dereferencing the reference may be more expensive than using values with known offsets.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In this case you could (and should) pass `std::string_view` (which was added in C++17) to avoid a possible heap allocation when passing a large string literal.

But if you needed a null-terminated string, then `std::string_view` wouldn't work, and you'd have to pass either `const std::string &` or a custom `string_view` replacement that's always null-terminated.

Or, if you wanted to copy the string somewhere, you'd instead pass `std::string` by value and then `std::move` it.

Comment: C++ 14 doesn't have std::string_view.

Comment: @kiner_shah Added a note.